# how to show agreement Page just one time in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I have a problem when working on app.I just want to create  agreement page,which will show just one time when the app load first time. After that the page will never show. but in my app that page always showing when the app loaded.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean variable in storage when the agreement is first displayed, then you check if this variable has been set before showing the agreement.

For example:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

constructor() {
  this.storage.get('agreement_displayed').then(val => {
    if (!val) {
     this.displayAgreement();
     this.storage.set('agreement_displayed', true);
    }
   });
 }
```

Comment: Yes I did this, but there is same problem

Comment: Please share your code so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: in app.component.ts this.authService.authState.subscribe(state=>{
      //   console.log(state);
      //   if(state){
      //     this.router.navigate(['tabs/tab1']);
      //   }
      //   else{
      //     this.router.navigate(['home']);